# Remove matching collection object from text file

Tags: string, powershell, file, text-files

I have a list of users that I am storing in a text file. I am trying to update the text file so it removes any user that match $NotExpiring users variable, which is a collection. I just can't figure out how I would update the text file properly if more than one user needs to be removed from text file.

Below is the full function. You can ignore most of it Just look under #Stuck Here to get to the point.

```
function Get-NotExpiring{

$NotExpiring=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$MatchedUser=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$textfiles = Get-ChildItem $email_dir



#Day of Span

$Days="20"

#Settings

$Date=Get-Date ((Get-Date).adddays($Days))

$Users=Get-ADUser -filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False)} -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, Mail | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ne $nul -and ($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" -gt ($NotExpDate.ToFileTime()))} | Select SamAccountName, Mail, DisplayName,@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={([datetime]::fromfiletime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).DateTime}}

#Magic

foreach ($Entry in $Users) {



$EntryDate = Get-date($Entry.ExpiryDate)

if ($EntryDate -gt $Date){



$Account = $Entry.SamAccountName

$ExpDate = $Entry.ExpiryDate

$NotExpiring.add($Account)

}

}



#STUCK HERE

foreach($file in $textfiles){

foreach ($user in $NotExpiring){

if((Get-Content "$email_dir\$file") -contains $user){

$temp_get = Get-Content $email_dir\$file | where {$_ -notmatch $user}

}}}



$temp_get}
```

I tried below but it doesn't seem to work if more than one user are $NotExpiring that are also in the existing textfile. Any help would be appreciated. I know this is a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
Get-Content $email_dir\$file | where {$_ -notmatch $user} | Set-Content <path>.txt
```

I was able to achieve exactly what I needed using the following solution.

```
foreach($file in $textfiles){ foreach ($user in $NotExpiring){

if((Get-Content "$email_dir\$file") -contains $user){ 
$MatchedUser.add($user) 
}}
Get-Content "$email_dir\$file" | Where {$MatchedUser -NotContains $_ } | Set Content "$temp_dir\$file" 

Copy-Item -path "$temp_dir\$file" -Destination "$email_dir\$file" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

Comment: Your saying "you can ignore most of it" tells me that everyone would benefit if you provided an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to test if the ADUser object collection contains a text string. i don't think that will work since the `-contains` array operator requires an exact match.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am taking the user names of all the users that are expiring in > 20 days and adding it to a collection object. Then I'm comparing a the collection to the text file and remove any matching users from text file.

Comment: @PCTekSupport - ah! thank you for the clarification. [*grin*] you may want to make the clear in your post that the collection is a collection of strings, not user objects.

Comment: It's not quite clear what is a format of your text file. You could use a regular expression to remove users.
And I wonder why you're using System.Collections.Generic.List instead of a native posh array.

Comment: Please edit your code and make it properly indented. As it is now, it is hard to read (where does a `foreach` block end, same for `if() {...}` etc. Try and make indenting code your second nature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you are trying to match two arrays.
With `where` you do it `foreach` object. Now you have to match the single object `$_` with the array `$user`.
Use:

```
...| where {$_ -notin $user}
```

or

```
...| where {$user -notcontains $_}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  Using the above information I was able to do exactly what i needed to do.   `foreach($file in $textfiles){
foreach ($user in $NotExpiring){
if((Get-Content "$email_dir\$file") -contains $user){
$MatchedUser.add($user)
}}
 Get-Content "$email_dir\$file" | Where {$MatchedUser -NotContains $_ } | Set-Content "$temp_dir\$file"
 Copy-Item -path "$temp_dir\$file"  -Destination  "$email_dir\$file"  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}`